# how to convert yyyy mm dd h:m:s to dd mm yyyy h:m:s?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
            In mysql data base the date is f=stored in the format of now() function like yyyy mm dd hh mm ss. But in frontend tool i want it like dd mm yyyy hh mm ss how can i convert it.


<?php 
 $addqry=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `exam`    (`user_id`,`sub_id`,`q_id`,`stud_ans`,`date_time`)VALUES ('$user', '$sub', '$ans', '$stud_ans',(Now()))");      
    $stud_ans=' ';                              
            if($addqry)
            {
            //result
            $date;
            $last_date=mysql_query("SELECT date_time FROM exam ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; ");
            while($res_last=mysql_fetch_array($last_date))
            {
            $date=$res_last['date_time'];
            }
            ?>
```

Here it gives the datetime in the format of 2014-04-12 15:34:40 but i want it like 12-04-2014 15:34:40

Comment: Also, don't use the `mysql_*` functions anymore. They are deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
$date=date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($res_last['date_time']));
```

for more :- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

No need to translate, you can just use MySQL to do it for you, with the [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_time, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$date_old = "2014-04-12 15:34:40";
$time_old = strtotime($date_old);
$date_new = date("d-m-Y h:i:s", $time_old);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `While` loop use this ,

```
 $date=date_format($res_last['date_time'],'d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

[**PHP-Date Manual**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just split it at the space and rejoin it.

```
$date = split($res_last['date_time'], " ");
$date = $date[1] . " " . $date[0];
```